# Capture sequence in string with lua patterns

Tags: lua

```
str = " for xxxx in (yyyy) do @ for xxxx in pairs(yyyy) do"
for cap in string.gmatch(str, "(for(.-)in(.*)do)") do
Print (cap)
end
```

In this code `xxxx` and `yyyy` are variables. also spaces are variables. So I try to capture only "`for xxxx in (yyyy)`". Also I need to capture "`for xxxx in pairs(yyyy) do`".

but my pattern captures both.
Please help.

Comment: also please notice spaces in pattern

Comment: You need the 2nd for-do-sequence only: `string.gmatch(str, "for.-do.-(for.-do)")`

Comment: `string.gmatch(str, "(for%s[%w_,%s]+%sin%s+pairs%s*%b()%s*do)")`

Comment: `string.gmatch(str, "(for%s[%w_,%s]+%sin%s*%b()%s*do)")`